# Oracle: Select values in date range with days where value is missing

Tags: database, oracle, view, oracle10g

I want to select values from table in range.
Something like this:

```
SELECT
  date_values.date_from,
  date_values.date_to,
  sum(values.value)
FROM values
  inner join date_values on values.id_date = date_values.id
  inner join date_units on date_values.id_unit = date_units.id
WHERE
  date_values.date_from >= '14.1.2012' AND
  date_values.date_to <= '30.1.2012' AND
  date_units.id = 4
GROUP BY
  date_values.date_from,
  date_values.date_to
ORDER BY
  date_values.date_from,
  date_values.date_to;
```

But this query give me back only range of days, where is any value. Like this:

```
14.01.12    15.01.12    66
15.01.12    16.01.12    4
17.01.12    18.01.12    8
...etc
```

(Here missing 16.01.12 to 17.01.12)

But I want to select missing value too, like this:

```
14.01.12    15.01.12    66
15.01.12    16.01.12    4
16.01.12    17.01.12    0
17.01.12    18.01.12    8
...etc
```

I can't use PL/SQL and if can you advise more general solution which can I expand for use on Hours, Months, Years; will be great.

Comment: it seems to me that you need an outer join. Dates 16.01.12 to 17.01.12 don't seem to have a corresponding record in the date_units table. Am I right?

Comment: Dates 16.01.12 to 17.01.12 are missing in date_values table. Date_units is table, where I store type of range (like days (date_units.id = 4), hours, months, weeks, years...). I think, I "just" need generate second temporary table of dates and do intersect with this two tables. Question is how to generate this table?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're providing `date_from` and `date_to`. If so, you can generate your list of dates first and then join to it to get the remainder of your result. Alternatively, you can `union` this query to your `date_values` table as `union` does a distinct this will remove any extra data.

If this is how the list of dates is generated:

```
 select to_date('14.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') + level - 1 as date_from
      , to_date('14.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') + level as date_to
   from dual
connect by level <= to_date('30.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') 
                  - to_date('14.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Your query might become

```
with the_dates as (
 select to_date('14.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') + level - 1 as date_from
      , to_date('14.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') + level as date_to
   from dual
connect by level <= to_date('30.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') 
                  - to_date('14.1.2012','dd.mm.yyyy')
         )
SELECT
  dv.date_from,
  dv.date_to,
  sum(values.value)
FROM values
  inner join ( select the_dates.date_from, the_dates.date_to, date_values.id
                 from the_dates
                 left outer join date_values
                   on the_dates.date_from = date_values.date_from ) dv
     on values.id_date = dv.id
  inner join date_units on date_values.id_unit = date_units.id
WHERE
  date_units.id = 4
GROUP BY
  dv.date_from,
  dv.date_to
ORDER BY
  dv.date_from,
  dv.date_to;
```

The `with` syntax is known as sub-query factoring and isn't really needed in this case but it makes the code cleaner.

I've also assumed that the `date` columns in `date_values` are, well, dates. It isn't obvious as you're doing a string comparison. You should always explicitly convert to a date where applicable and you should always store a date as a date. It saves a lot of hassle in the long run as it's impossible for things to be input incorrectly or to be incorrectly compared.